# VerificationException from DotNetOpenAuth RP

Tags: openid

I'm trying to integrate open id into a site, but I have a problem due to this open ticket:
"http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/ticket/163"
Can you give me a workaround, please?
Maybe indicate an older version?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, forcing a stateless RP (dumb mode) would workaround the issue.  Or you could wait until [tomorrow's build of DotNetOpenAuth](http://teamcity.dotnetopenauth.net:82/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt49&tab=buildTypeStatusDiv) comes out (v3.4.4.10121) which will have a "fix".

At the root it's a CLR bug, so by "fix", I mean the workaround is built into the library to catch the error and swallow them.